# How to avoid loosing focus on click of anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an input type text element and anchor element, Now I don't want to loose focus on click of that anchor tag if the focus is already on input text element. I have tried following but it does not work.

HTML:

```
<input type = 'text' value='click here first' />
<a href='javascript:void(null);' id='nothing'>do nothing</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#nothing').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Above does not work for me. Can somebody tell me what is missing here?

Comment: You can explicitly set the focus back to the input element..

Comment: Yes I can, but consider if the part of text is selected then I don't want to loose the selection as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced similar problem try using 'mousedown' instead of click event.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BHSYn/)

```
<input type = 'text' value='click here first' />
<a href='javascript:void(null);' id='nothing'>clicking this does not loose the focus from input field!</a>

$('#nothing').bind('mousedown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The anchor will always loose focus when clicking something else, the way to get around it is by resetting the focus to the input:

```
var active = null;

$('#nothing').on({
    mousedown: function() {
        active = document.activeElement;
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        if (active) active.focus();
    },
    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SjY3x/1/)